# How to pop ViewController to root when connected to navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

Im trying to call `popToRootViewController` function from a view controller that is connected to a `navigationController`. When i removed that `navigationController` im able to go to my `RootViewController`. But if there is a navigation controller connected to (My case: TableViewController ) `ViewController`. the `popToRootViewController` will end up with the `navigationController`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        Utilities.shared.clearTokens()
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to popup to your root viewController when user click sign out  you should cahnge the app root controller you can  do it like this

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let newViewController = let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let rootViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"your identifier")
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
```

because  `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)` will pop to root controller on your current navigation stack

Comment: Where should i write this. In appDelegate?

Comment: replacement for this navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)  inside didSelectRowAt

Comment: I got the same result when added this line. Can we implement this logic ?`navigationController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)`

(Poping until there is no navigation controller)

Comment: Yes you can but it’s not the best practice I think